# How does Android logcat work?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

How does logcat works? Does it output the logs only when connected to a reader else it redirects everything to /dev/null?
I'll follow up with a different question based on this. Thank you

Comment: Connected to a reader, an android device? It is logging all the time I believe. Also, do not follow up with another question, `questions should be specific`, so create another.

Comment: Android is open source, so you [can read the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master) for the parts you're interested in.

Comment: LogCat is logging all the time, even the device is not connected , even when the code is not executing.

Comment: Btw, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Does [logcat] output the logs only when connected to a reader", but _"Logs from various applications and portions of the system are collected in a series of circular buffers, which then can be viewed and filtered by the logcat command."_ ([source](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html))

Comment: @Michael unfortunately reading the source code is not always as easy at it sounds as some people might not be proficient in all the programming languages out there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In older versions of Android, there's a set of circular buffers in the kernel.  Each log (main, slog, events, radio) has its own buffer.  The original size was 64K, but that was increased in subsequent releases.

Recent versions of Android have moved toward user-space handling of logging.

Log collection is happening continuously, with older logs overwritten by newer logs.

The logcat command reads from one or more circular buffers, e.g. the default command reads from the main and system logs and interleaves them by timestamp.  It isn't running unless you run it.